# Visual C++ 2010 is extremely slow/unusable. Can't type and have to minimize to refresh the window/view code

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I downloaded Visual C++ 2010 express and am shocked at how completely slow/unusable it is. I have a pretty beefy computer (4 gigs ram, 3.2ghz dual core, Radeon hd4890) and I literally cannot even type when I have opened up a solution. To even see the code in the first place after opening up a .cpp I have to minimize visual c++ and maximize it again to "refresh" it. Anyone have similar problems to this or know how to fix it? 2008 worked like a charm for me but I would really like to get 2010 working for class. Thanks!

*Edit further info:*

-Sometimes if i restart my computer enough I can boot up VS2010 and then it seems to work fine. It is completely random though.

-My cpu/ram usage seems fine having VS open
-All drivers/bios up to date

If anyone needs any further diagnostic information from me to help diagnose the problem ill get it ASAP.

~~~EDIT SOLUTION?~~~

Hmmm new update... messing around in options->environment->general there are three boxes for "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance", "enable rich client visual experience" and "use hardware acceleration if available"." I unchecked all of them and it seems to be working fine now. Does anyone know what these options really mean and the advantages/disadvantages to turning them off.

Comment: VS 2010 works pretty fine on my 3-year old laptop as well.  ( Core 2 Duo T5250 @ 1.5Ghz / 2GB /Win 7/ 8600m GT )

Comment: Does this happen with ALL .cpp files and Visual Studio projects? Or does it only happen with some?

Comment: It seems to be happening with all .cpp files. I also open .sln files too for example code. Even when I make a new project it doesn't work half the time. The funny thing is I can actually build the solution when I import i and run it successfully. I just can't edit it the entire code editing window/solution explorer is just unresponsive and laggy. For example if I highlight a block of text in the code window it won't highlight, but if i minimize and re maximize visual studio the code will be highlighted.

Comment: Could this problem have something to do with VS 2010 using a different display toolkit/engine (i think that's the word) than the other Visual Studios? Has there been any bugs with this new engine?

Comment: Hmmm new update... messing around in options->environment->general there are three boxes for "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance", "enable rich client visual experience" and "use hardware acceleration if available"." I unchecked all of them and it *seems* to be working fine now. Does anyone know what these options really mean and the advantages/disadvantages to turning them off.

Answer (score 1):

There's something else wrong here. I'm running an old AMD 4200+ with 3gb of ram and my C++ 2010 works like a dream. 
If you previously installed the beta version uninstall it and try reinstalling express.

Answer (score 1):

As @Spidey said, there's something else at play. VS2010 is not that slow by itself. Check to see if you have any background processes that might be slowing it down.

Your specific problem sounds somewhat like a graphics issue. Try installing the latest driver for your graphics card and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I have the latest drivers :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this Microsoft Support article can help:

[Visual Studio 2010 runs faster when the Windows Automation API 3.0 is installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981741)

**EDIT**

As the above article doesn't apply to Windows 7, I can see two other possibilities:

1. Corruption in Windows : See [How to Repair Windows 7 System Files with System File Checker](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)
2. Corruption in Visual Studio : See [Repairing Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx#repair)

Comment: Alas I have Windows 7 x64 so I think this is installed by default (I will run windows update optional just in case), and it won't let me install the vista one either.

Comment: Further research shows that Windows 7 is shipped with Windows Automation API 3.0 installed. See my edit.